# How to parse a XML string with data within a label

Tags: java, parsing

I'd like to parse this kind of XML String:

```
<Objects>
   <Object type="crs" obj_id="192">
      <Title>Course 1</Title>
      <Description>this is description</Description>
      <CreateDate>2012-10-16 12:53:12</CreateDate>
      <LastUpdate>2012-10-16 12:53:54</LastUpdate>
   </Object>

   <Object type="frm" obj_id="202">
      <Title>Forum 1</Title>
      <Description>this is description</Description>
      <CreateDate>2012-10-30 01:06:41</CreateDate>
      <LastUpdate>2012-10-30 01:06:41</LastUpdate>
   </Object>
</Objects>
```

I have parsed XML Strings with the same structure but just with the label < Object >. Now I want to get the information within label Object to get the string of type="xxx".

This is how I do those kind of  parse:

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource xml = new InputSource();
        xml.setCharacterStream(xmlSTring);
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Object");

        // iterate objects 
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
           Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
           // get first attribute
           NodeList ref_id = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
           Element line = (Element) ref_id.item(0);
           System.out.println("title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
private static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "?";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im a newbie and I'm not sure what is a DTD, but if it helps, I get the XML String from a soap request, I don't edit it.

I mean, I just get this code and no more.

Comment: Oh yes... searching I have a .dtd document.

Comment: A DTD teaches the parser to expect data in a certain kind of format. If your SOAP requests always look like this, you might be well served by writing your own... [take a look at this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition)

Comment: Right, so, if you do `SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); Schema s = sf.newSchema(new File("dtd_file.dtd")); dbf.setSchema(s);` then your parser will be a lot better at reading the XML. Also, use `.getAttribute("type")` as @BevynQ suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main loop

```
element.getAttribute("type");
```

should get you what you want.

instead of using dom you could look at stax

[jee5 stax tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html)

Comment: Oh that was a stupid error, thank you BevynQ.

And Thank you all for your propositions. I'll check stax.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JAXB for a problem like this.  When you have an example XML file, you can generate an xsd with a program called [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html).  This is a schema for your xml document that I generated using that program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Objects">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Object"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Object">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Title"/>
        <xs:element ref="Description"/>
        <xs:element ref="CreateDate"/>
        <xs:element ref="LastUpdate"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="obj_id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="CreateDate" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="LastUpdate" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Then you can use JAXB to generate objects for your xml document and bind the xml to those objects.

Comment: If you are going to go the JAXB route, I would make a few changes to this XSD.  First, set the two date fields to xs:date.  This will give you Calendar objects when you generate the binding.  Also, Trang picked the names Object and Objects for your types.  I would change those to make the generated code more readable or customize the names with an xjb binding file.